# When using Angular.js, how to retain form data after submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have used the basic angular script which update what ever you type in the input field on any element we specify, real time...

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html ng-app>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
        <hr>
        <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Im new to Angular. I used this on may rails app. But the problem is, the field I used ng-model will reset its valu after submit. Even setting the 'value' attribute won't work. How can I fix this?

Exact code generated from my rails application :

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/members" class="custom" id="new_member" method="post">

      <div class="row collapse text-field">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
          <h3>Add Member : </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns left inline">
          <h3 class="subheader inline">&nbsp;{{newEntry.name}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>



        <div class="row collapse text-field">
          <div class="small-3 columns"> 
            <label class="prefix" for="member_name">Full Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-7 columns left">
            <input class="input" id="member_name" name="member[name]" ng-model="newEntry.name" type="text" value="gj" />
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row collapse text-field">
          <div class="small-3 columns"> 
            <label class="prefix" for="member_address">Address</label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 columns">
            <textarea class="input" height="115" id="member_address" name="member[address]">
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-9 columns" ><input class="button radius" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Member" /></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Note : I haven't used an ng-controller. Im new to Angular. If its required, please tell me how to convert the above to the controller. I can get the value of the field and send it back to the form in rails. Its there in a variable. But Angular keeps wiping it!

**Note2** : This problem persist only for the input field I used angular-model.. All the other fields retained the data!

Comment: When you say "submit", what is it you are submitting? - Your example doesn't seem to have a form or a submit button. Perhaps if you include the exact code you are trying to use along with your Angular controller? 

Keep in mind that angular will not retain data between requests. You will need to write that data to local storage / cookie or send it server side to be stored in a database, then reloaded and assigned back to the `$scope.yourName` variable within your controller

Comment: @JoeGreen Sorry for the issue :) I have included the full code. The field's data can be retrieved after submitting through rails. I tried to add that value as the value attribute in the input field. But angular wipes it. This problem persist only for the input field I used angular-model.. All the other fields retained the data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is not the best solution but you could do this:

`<input type="text" ng-init="yourName = 'Your Value Goes Here'" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">`

ng-init directives are run when the app intialises, so your value will be assigned to angular's internal "yourName" model and be updated in the view accordingly.

That would solve your problem but its not the best way. Hopefully that will get you going for now - I'll try and post a more "ideal" solution shortly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks it worked! After converting to Ruby, it looks like this : 'ng-init' => "newEntry.name = '#{@member.name}'"   . I will wait for a better answer if you think this is not appropriate until tomorrow. If there's no good answer, I will accept this.